# How to add self-signed ssl certificate for loopback4?

Tags: typescript, ssl, loopback

I am working on microservice project based on loopback-next(loopback4), it is simple service so that I would like to make the application as the SSL endpoint. But I could not find any guide/doc or example about how to configure SSL in the generated  code from lb4. Does anyone have experience on the ssl configuration for loopback4? Many thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, to add rest configuration in src/index.ts according to [Enable HTTPS](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html#enable-https)